# setting a custom margin between view of a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make `recyclerview` in which I can put a custom margin on view item based on an id in android

I tried custome adapter with a different view which we can put in one recycler view but I need only one view and only want to do is put custom margin between view based on id.

```
if (category_detail.getId()==0){
        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginLayoutParams =
                (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) rec_discount.getLayoutParams();
        marginLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 500, 0, 0);
        rec_discount.setLayoutParams(marginLayoutParams);


 }
```

[image]

Comment: So you need different margin sizes based on id?

Comment: yes i want to make design like in above image using recyclerview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ItemDecoration to achieve this.

```
public class SpacesItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
    private int space;

    public SpacesItemDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
        outRect.bottom = space;

        // Add top margin only for the first item to avoid double space between items
        if(parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == 0) {
            outRect.top = space;
        }
    }
}
```

This will add a margin of "space" pixels on the left, right and bottom sides of all views in the recycler view. You can customize as per your requirements.

To use this class you can do this:

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SpacesItemDecoration(10));
```

Comment: but it works for one view only if i put margin to more then one view then only last one get the margins. @Vikas Malhotra

Comment: @yuvrajsinh you don't need to give any extra margin in your code. Just add the item decoration. If you still face the issue, I recommend sharing your code snippet so that I can help further.